# Implement Nodejs int HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm learning back-end development using ***Nodejs***. And from what I've seen so far, it seems like there's no way to integrate it with an already made website built with plain ***HTML*** and ***CSS***.

I've been told that when running the `index.html` file locally without `Nodejs`, the web browser handles the `css` automatically, but when using node, how do I get both `html` and `css` to display?

I have an `HTML` page and a href to my `CSS` file. When trying to use `Nodejs` to make requests and serve my `HTML` page, it displays the page without styling and completely ignores the `CSS` file I'm referencing within the `HTML`.

I've tried `express()` and `ejs` but is it at all possible to use what I've already made in HTML/CSS?

Here's the source code, any explanation would be HUGE help:

```
const http =  require('http');//importing http
var fs = require('fs');//file stream

let handleRequest = (request, response) =>{
    response.writeHead(200,{
        'Content-type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function(error, data){
        if(error){
            response.writeHead(404)
            response.write('File not found!');
        }else{
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });

   console.log('request was made: ' + request.url);//logg all requests made
}

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(3000);
```

Comment: nodejs serves NO files by default.  So, your code right does exactly one thing - no matter what URL is requested, you send out `index.html`.  But, as soon as the browser parses index.html, it's going to send requests for your CSS files.  When your web server gets those requests, it sends back `index.html`. That's why they don't work.  If you're going to go with this handcoded web server (instead of a simple framework like Express), then you are going to have to implement some sort of `if/else` or `switch` or table lookup that uses `req.url` to see what was requested,then send the correct file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render html inside a node app. You have many ways to do it
1. Server side rendering using templates like ejs pug etc

2. You can use html with no templates too. But you have to make a /public folder, and inside of it, from the app.js select the path of your index.html using the fs module
3. Just only node to make apis and then call it from the client with vainlila html or frameworks like vue

I suggest start a node js course.